# Частое употребление частицы "бы"

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, тавтология, частицы

Существует ли какое-то ограничение на количество употреблений частицы "бы"? В этом предложении "бы" употребляется дважды, и хочу узнать, можно ли оставить всё как есть: "Результат мог оказаться и плачевным, но это **бы** ранило лишь родителей и преподавателей; меня же такой итог никак не тронул **бы**"?

Comment: Правил, увы, нет про повторение "бы".

Answer (score 1):

Про ограничение количества "бы" в одном предложении правил нет. Теоретически тут можно приплести тавтологию, но и она, как явление, ошибкой не является, а порой — может быть авторским приёмом. Вопрос лишь в том, будет ли предложение с большим количеством "бы" читабельно и не будет ли потерян его смысл при попытке сократить число этих самых "бы". Приведу несколько примеров из "Нацкорпуса", где число частиц "бы" в одном предложении достаточно велико — три или больше (что, повторюсь, ошибкой не является). Да и в целом дискуссии тут возможны разве что по поводу излишества соответствующих частиц и читабельности текста.

*Ну, не было **бы** у него компьютера, может, ещё **бы** хуже было, он **бы** где-нибудь с компанией болтался, пил **бы** водку в подъезде…* [Елена Павлова. Вместе мы эту пропасть одолеем! // «Даша», 2004]

*Будь оно на самом деле, вокруг нас постоянно совершались **бы** чудеса: можно было **бы** выпить вино из запечатанной бутылки, в запертом помещении вдруг появлялись **бы** какие-то предметы, закон сохранения энергии и импульса нарушался **бы** на каждом шагу…* [Владилен Барашенков. Верен ли закон Ньютона? // «Знание -- сила», 2003]

*Если **бы** закон о взаимном страховании разрешил адвокатам создавать в субъектах Федерации общества взаимного страхования в форме основанного на членстве некоммерческого партнерства, имущество, переданное адвокатами такому обществу, становилось **бы** его собственностью, и адвокат был **бы** вправе участвовать в управлении делами и получать информацию о деятельности общества.* [Г. Шаров. Федеральный закон «Об адвокатской деятельности и адвокатуре в Российской Федерации» о страховании риска ответственности адвоката (2 часть) // «Адвокат», 2004.12.01]

*Но если **бы** в распоряжении учёных находилось только несколько "полуроманских" языков вроде албанского, то, применяя к этим языкам сравнительный метод, выработанный индоевропейским языковедением, пришлось **бы** восстанавливать их "праязык", причём нероманские элементы этих языков пришлось **бы** либо оставлять невыясненными, либо объяснять при помощи сложных и искусственных комбинаций, которые непременно отразились **бы** на восстановленном "праязыке".* [Н. С. Трубецкой. Мысли об индоевропейской проблеме (1938)]

*Смотришь на это и думаешь: каждый из нас хотел **бы** гордиться своей страной и с удовольствием носил **бы** не фраки и джинсы, а косоворотки и штаны, не блейзеры и мини-юбки, а душегреи и сарафаны, была **бы** только эта одежда красивой и современной.* [Народный костюм: архаика или современность? // «Народное творчество», 2004]

**ВЫВОД**

Можно писать сколько угодно "бы" в одном предложении (желательно, с оглядкой на читабельность). В вашем конкретном случае вполне можно оставить так, как есть.